# Python: Read the content of a variable

Tags: python

For example I have:

```
x = True and True
print x
```

I want to be able to do something like:

```
x = True and True
print "The answer to ", some_function(x), "is", x
```

Such that the program reads:

> The answer to True and True is True.

Is there a `some_function()` that can read the content as a string instead of solving as a boolean?

Sorry in advance for any confusion on the wording of the question.

Comment: You mean you have a Python expression stored as a string?  Like `x = 'True and True'`?  In that case, look at `eval()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write it as a string:

```
x = 'True and True'
```

and evaluate it using [`eval`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/functions.html):

```
print "The answer to ", x, "is", eval(x)
```

---

```
>>> x = 'True and True'
>>> print "The answer to ", x, "is", eval(x)
The answer to  True and True is True
```

Comment: It may be worth adding the usual warning about `eval`: it shouldn't be used on untrusted input. For example, if `x` is populated from a web service and the result is going into a log, the input must be sanitized (as much as possible) before running it through `eval`.

Answer (score 0):

What you're asking for is basically not possible in Python; expressions are evaluated immediately in Python and the interpreter does not "remember" what expression generated a particular value.

However, by changing your code slightly you can achieve a similar effect with `eval`:

```
expr = 'True and True'
print "The answer to", expr, "is", eval(expr)
```

As usual, with `eval`, never pass anything that you didn't write yourself (because it opens a security hole otherwise).